# Append dictionary items to another dictionary in Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

Hope this is possible:

I'm using Ansible inventories, and trying to reference one dictionary in another.

```
ansible/group_vars/myapi/user-list.yml

  sysadmin_settings:
  - { shell: "/bin/bash", groups: "hardworkers" }

  myapi_admin_users:
  - { state: "present", name: "my.user1", shell: "{{ sysadmin_settings.shell }}", groups: "{{ sysadmin_settings.groups }}" }
  - { state: "present", name: "my.user2", shell: "{{ sysadmin_settings.shell }}", groups: "{{ sysadmin_settings.groups }}" }
```

But I get a "List object has no attribute shell"

Which I though I was what I was looking up in the first dict.

Ideally I could do something akin to:

```
adminapi_admin_users:
  - { state: "present", name: "my.user1", type: "sysadmin" }
```

And reference `sysadmin` variables when I call items in my playbook, by concatenating them with `myapi_admin.groups` for example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing in up your YAML with some JSON (or Jinja). Typically, what you appear to want would be written like this:

```
sysadmin_settings:
  shell: "/bin/bash"
  groups: "hardworkers"

myapi_admin_users:
  - state: "present"
    name: "my.user1"
    shell: "{{ sysadmin_settings.shell }}"
    groups: "{{ sysadmin_settings.groups }}"
  - state: "present"
    name: "my.user2"
    shell: "{{ sysadmin_settings.shell }}"
    groups: "{{ sysadmin_settings.groups }}"
```

That works for me on my system. [Ansible YAML docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) are worth a look and have a useful reference to common mistakes.